# setPassword() method is not working in Lightning Component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String setPassword( String userId, String password) {

    User usr =[SELECT id, Name FROM User WHERE Username =: userId];
    System.setPassword(usr.Id, password);

}
```

Getting Error:

> FATAL_ERROR System.UnexpectedException: INVALID_SESSION_ID: This session is not valid for use with the API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is known Issue from Salesforce
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A00000031PwQAI